# Evaluate $I=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{(x^2+x+1)dx}{(x^3+x+1)\sqrt{x}}$

Tags: calculus, integration, polynomials, definite-integrals

Evaluate $$I=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{(x^2+x+1)dx}{(x^3+x+1)\sqrt{x}}$$

My try:

Letting $\sqrt{x}=t$ we get

$$I=2\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{t^4+t^2+1}{(t^6+t^2+1)}\,dt$$

Now

$$t^4+t^2+1=(t^2+1)^2-(t^2+1)+1$$

$$t^6+t^2+1=(t^2+1)^3-2(t^2+1)^2+(t^2+1)+1$$

Any clue then?

Comment: Please share the source. If I recall correctly this is  an open problem from Brilliant dot org, although I have to search a little in order to show it.

Comment: Here: https://brilliant.org/problems/integral-in-the-form-of-an-algebraic-equation

Comment: Yes you are right

Comment: Although the integral has a closed form, it is an egregiously complicated combination of nested radicals. It will be much better to focus on the original problem itself for your mental sanity, which has a very simple answer.

Answer (score 10):

Let me attack the original problem, as stated in [Brilliant.org](https://brilliant.org/problems/integral-in-the-form-of-an-algebraic-equation/).

> **Question.** If
>
> $$ \alpha = \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^2 + x + 1}{x^3 + x + 1} \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{x}}, $$
>
> then what is the value of $31\alpha^4 - 40\alpha^2 - 24\alpha$?

*Remark.* Once we identify the value of $31\alpha^4 - 40\alpha^2 - 24\alpha$, the problem of determining $\alpha$ reduces to solving the quartic equation. Since [such formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function) is known, it suffices to answer to the question.

---

**Step 1 - Reduction to algebraic sum.** First, write $p(x) = x^2 + x + 1$ and $q(x) = x^3 + x + 1$ for simplicity. Then $\alpha$ is written as

$$ \alpha = \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{p(x)}{q(x)\sqrt{x}} \, \mathrm{d}x. $$

Let $\operatorname{Log}$ denote the complex logarithm so that $\Im\operatorname{Log}(z) \in [0, 2\pi)$. In other words, the branch cut is chosen as $[0, \infty)$. Then by employing the standard keyhole contour, we may write

\begin{align*}
\alpha
&= \frac{1}{2\pi} \left( \int_{\infty-i0^+}^{-i0^+} \frac{p(z)}{q(z)}e^{-\frac{1}{2}\operatorname{Log}(z)} \, \mathrm{d}z + \int_{i0^+}^{\infty+i0^+} \frac{p(z)}{q(z)}e^{-\frac{1}{2}\operatorname{Log}(z)} \, \mathrm{d}z \right) \\
&= i \sum_{q(x) = 0} \frac{ p(x)}{q'(x)} e^{-\frac{1}{2}\operatorname{Log}(x)}, \tag{1}
\end{align*}

where the sum in the last line runs over all complex $x$'s solving $p(x)=0$, which itself is a consequence of the residue theorem.

**Step 2 - Identifying the nature of the sum.** Since $q(x)$ is a cubic polynomial with only simple zeros, the sum in $\text{(1)}$ involves 3 terms, which we write as $z_1, z_2, z_3$. Then

$$\alpha = z_1 + z_2 + z_3. $$

Also, consider

$$ y = \left( \frac{i p(x)}{q'(x)} e^{-\frac{1}{2}\operatorname{Log}(x)} \right)^2 = -\frac{p(x)^2}{xq'(x)^2} $$

and let $\mathcal{Z} = \{z_1^2, z_2^2, z_3^2\}$ be the set of all possible values of $y$ given $q(x) = 0$. Rearranging this equality, we obtain $ yxq'(x)^2 + p(x)^2 = 0 $, and so, we observe that

- $ q(x) $ and $yxq'(x)^2 + p(x)^2$ shares a root whenever $y \in \mathcal{Z}$.

On the other hand, if we regard both as polynomials with coefficients in $\mathbb{C}[y]$, then the [*resultant*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant) between them is given by

$$ \operatorname{res}\left(q(x), yxq'(x)^2 + p(x)^2 \right) = 961y^3 - 620y^2 + 131y - 9. $$

Since the resultant between two complex polynomials is zero exactly when they share a root, it follows that $\mathcal{Z} = \{ y : 961y^3 - 620y^2 + 131y - 9 \}$, or equivalently,

$$ 961y^3 - 620y^2 + 131y - 9 = 961(y - z_1^2)(y - z_2^2)(y - z_3^2). $$

In particular, by [Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas), we check that

$$
z_1^2 + z_2^2 + z_3^2 = \frac{620}{961} = \frac{20}{31}, \qquad
z_1^2 z_2^2 + z_2^2 z_3^2 + z_3^2 z_1^2 = \frac{131}{961}, \\
z_1^2 z_2^2 z_3^2 = \frac{9}{961} = \left(\frac{3}{31}\right)^2.
$$

Moreover, although not immediate from the previous computation, we can in fact check that $z_1 z_2 z_3$ is not a negative real number, and so, $z_1 z_2 z_3 = \frac{3}{31}$.

**Step 3 - Conclusion.** From the conclusion of the previous step, we can identify the equation that $\alpha$ satisfies. Indeed,

\begin{align*}
\alpha^2
= \left( z_1^2 + z_2^2 + z_3^2 \right) + 2\left( z_1z_2 + z_2z_3 + z_3z_1 \right) 
= \frac{20}{31}+ 2\left( z_1z_2 + z_2z_3 + z_3z_1 \right)
\end{align*}

and

$$ \left( \alpha^2 - \frac{20}{31} \right)^2
= 4 \left( z_1^2 z_2^2 + z_2^2 z_3^2 + z_3^2 z_1^2 \right) + 8 z_1 z_2 z_3 (z_1 + z_2 + z_3) = \frac{524}{961} + \frac{24}{31}\alpha.$$

Rearranging, we obtain

$$ 31 \alpha^4 - 40\alpha^2 - 24\alpha = 4. $$

Moreover, it turns out that this equation has the unique positive zero, which is exactly $\frac{1}{\pi}$ times what WolframAlpha yields (as demonstrated in @Infiaria's answer).

Comment: Where is $31\alpha^4 - 40\alpha^2 - 24\alpha$ coming from ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, Frankly speaking, I have no idea why. For me, it was already a miracle that $$\alpha=\sum_{k=1}^{3}\sqrt{\xi_k}$$ holds. (Although it is straightforward that the square of each summand corresponds to zero of $p(u)$ by the choice of substitution, it seems not entirely clear to me as to why the sign of each square root concur with the principal branch.)

Comment: [I am extremely sorry to put the following comment. : ( ]  i haven't understood the very first step where you have written $\alpha$ as a sum. Is this a part of complex analysis ? Can you please tell me which things are required to understand this ? Frankly speaking i haven't taken the complex analysis course, is the following explanation has something to do with residues theorem?

Comment: @MDesmond, No worries :) And as you have correctly guessed, this is related to residue theorem. I was lazy enough not to straighten out every detail.

Comment: Ramanujan would have liked this. +1 but he would rather get the integral in radicals form and say that it was obviously a root of such and such equation.

Comment: @Paramanand Singh, the author, Srinivasa  Raghava, of the problem has closed form(complicated form)  and this is still unsolved on RMM site.

Answer (score 6):

According to [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral%20%28x%5E4%2Bx%5E2%2B1%29%2F%28x%5E6%2Bx%5E2%2B1%29%20dx%20from%200%20to%20infinity), the answer is

$$\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{186}}\left(\sqrt{40-14\sqrt[3]{\frac{2}{47-3\sqrt{93}}}-\sqrt[3]{4\left(47-3\sqrt{93}\right)}}+\sqrt{80+14\sqrt[3]{\frac{2}{47-3\sqrt{93}}}+\sqrt[3]{4\left(47-3\sqrt{93}\right)}+36\sqrt{\frac{186}{40-14\sqrt[3]{\frac{2}{47-3\sqrt{93}}}-\sqrt[3]{4\left(47-3\sqrt{93}\right)}}}}\right)$$

which is approximately $4.34952$. Alternatively, it is simply the positive solution of

$$\frac{31}{4\pi^4}x^4 - \frac{10}{\pi^2}x^2 - \frac{6}{\pi}x - 1 = 0 $$

Comment: Oh my god the answer is too heavy

Comment: Do you know how to see that it is a root of that polynomial?

Comment: What i guess is, there is nothing to do wih integral, the key is hidden in the way the polynomial is constructed.

Comment: I do not know how you got the last result but simpler would be $2\pi r_1$ where $r_1$ is the positive root of $124 t^4-40 t^2-12 t-1=0$